# iPhone switch/move view

Tags: iphone, view

I have a question about the correct way to switch views for an iPhone app I am developing.

The simplistic application architecture is as follows. On opening app user is displayed with a login screen. The username and password authenticate via a webservice. If the user credentials are correct I would like to switch/move to a 'menu' view which will be the 'home' for further tasks performed by the user. i.e. they will branch out from this menu view and then once finished on the branches they can return to the 'menu' view.

I actually have this model working but I have a suspicion I am not coding it correctly for my needs. My code for switching view is...

`MainMenuViewController *menuvc = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:menuvc animated:YES];`

Seeing as once the user has logged in the login screen is not needed, should I be using modal view functions? What alerted me to the fact that this may not be correct is that in the apple documentation it says that modal views should only be temporary, whereas I want the 'menu' view to be the home of the navigation.

I don't want to use the built in UINavigation bars.

In addition should I and if so where should I be releasing menuvc i.e. call [menuvc release]. Also should I be releasing the login view now that I don't need it anymore?

Thanks in advance
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a Modal View Controller for your login screen.

The Main View Controller should be your "root", then if the user isn't logged in you present the modal login view. 
If the user IS logged in, then it will just show your Main VC with it's navigation elements.

Answer (score 0):

u can add menuview.view to that self.view and then u can release the menuvc

[self.view addsubview:menuvc.view];

[menuvc release];